# Designing better GUIs?

Tags: c#, user-interface

I've been using C# for a while now but haven't really homed in my UI design skills. At the time I design them, I find myself enjoying the design, but later on, I look back on it and see horrible work. An example comes to mind from my project at work where I had to use 127 buttons to represent 127 computers in our lab. :/

I was wondering if anyone could refer me to a site or book that would teach good UI design?

Thanks!

Comment: 37signals are a good source for enlightenment on this topic.

Comment: BTW whilst it may not be the best implementation, if you have only users with big monitors, 127 buttons in a spatial layout might actually be very usable - I can't judge without a bit more context and I'd like to give you the benefit of the doubt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe **observation** and **instincts** helps tremendously.

Play with applications and dig deep into the functionality they implemented. Especially look at Apple, since they revolve around aesthetics.  What worked? What didn't?  Why did it work?  Start asking yourself questions as you tinker with web sites and software.

Then I would play around and design some concepts. Show these concepts to friends, both technical and non.  Ask them questions like, "Add a new drink to the list" or "Find x for me." See how they react and differ from each other.  Did someone with a technical background notice buttons faster than the non-techies?  Should you combine elements together?

This stuff should be fun. After all, this is like building a complete Lego set and showing it off to your friend.  He/she get's to see, touch, and play with your creation.

Comment: I like the comments about testing it on your friends, but using instinct for UI design is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 7):

Joel Spolsky wrote a book called User Interface Design for Programmers, which is a good read, and an abridged version [can be found online](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000057.html).

Comment: +1 for pimping a site owner and because Joel himself edited the question at the same time you were posting the response. Too rich to pass up.

Comment: Sycophantism is a virtue now?

Comment: There is no sycophancy in my answer, it's a perfectly legitimate response to the question, and, incidentally, was posted before Joel made the edit.

Comment: Your answer was perfectly fine. I was just reacting to Randolpho's response, who appears to be praising your answer not on its own merits, but because you mentioned a name that he recognizes.

Comment: It's a great book. I recommend buying it because the book deserves to be paid for and the pictures are better in print.

Answer (score 3):

[The Design of Everyday Things](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0385267746)
by Donald A. Norman

[The Humane Interface](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201379376)
by Jef Raskin

Answer (score 2):

The most important to focus on first would be the work flow of things. Try to find the goals the user  has and create a model the is as effective as possible in reaching that goal. Also read a lot around this one of the best books to start with is The [Inmates are running the asylum](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672316498)

I would suggest lots of sketches here. Make sure you keep it simplistic to focus on what and where things are placed and less on how they look. A tool like [balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/) is great for fast UI mockups. Also go through UI patterns here to come up with concepts that work, Tidwells book [Designing Interfaces](http://designinginterfaces.com/) is great and also Infragistics new [patterns site](http://quince.infragistics.com/#/Main) are great resources

Now you have an idea on what you want to do, now is the time to put together the interface. Along the way from the first sketch to the last pixel - always user test.

And don't always follow the UI guidelines, it is OK to break them if you have a good reason. And last, you will only get one free unrelated 3D effect in an interface :)

Comment: upvoted because of everything other than "inmates" - I hate the way Cooper hands out blame without mentioning management

Answer (score 1):

Building on Vinay's answer, integrating with your target platform is always going to be of paramount importance when designing an interface.  If you were developing on Windows, make sure you stay true to the look, feel, and usability expectations of that platform.  The interface guidelines are always going to be a jumping off point, though some are better than others.  For my money's worth, the [GNOME Human Interface Guidelines](http://library.gnome.org/devel/hig-book/stable/) are a great set of guidelines to designing user-friendly interfaces, even if you aren't using GTK.

On a more general note, learning good design is really learning to *recognize* good design. Find some applications that are really intuitive and then mimic their layout, style, etc.  Then, when you are struggling with how to implement a particular feature, find a suitable analogue in a one of those other applications.  You will want to pay particular attention to issues like grouping, tabbing, shortcuts, dialog modality, etc.  I think you will find that very few good design principles are dependent on the language you are programming in, except in so far as it may influence the toolkit and platform that you target.

Comment: Don't you think there are some other things of higher importance, such as visibility, elimination of modes, constraints, etc. etc.? The strategy you promote is just copying without understanding WHY a design is good. This is essentially what microsoft did with windows, copying all mac OS's mistakes.

Comment: I thought I had implied that "WHY" was important when I used the word "recognize".  You can't recognize if you don't understand.  But both come with the practice of careful observation.

Comment: As to copying: fitting in with one's environment is paramount with software.  You might build a better widget, but if it works in an diametrically opposite manner to 99% of the widgets the user sees, that may not be a bonus.  An efficient design is a product of execution AND expectation.

Comment: You can indeed recognize that leonardo was a great artist without knowing how he did it, or why his art is great. Efficiency has nothing to do with expectation, except for the first few uses. They are complimentary colors. Expectation only counts the first few uses. Then it's all up to good design.

Comment: "fitting in with one's environment is paramount with software." It's important, but it's not paramount. There are at least half dozen other aspects to ui design that are more important. If the vendor's style guide has codified bad design, then is it really such a great idea to follow religiously?

Comment: You make a compelling argument, but, at least in my day to day development the benefits of familiarity outweigh the potential costs of following platform dogmatism.  None of the guides mentioned are in the business of codifying bad design.  Sure, some of it IS bad, but its better than winging it.

Comment: And the notion that one is going to go from "127 buttons" to the sort of intuitive design your suggesting without some intermediary step does not seem plausible or pragmatic to me.  I would rather an app succeed at "just fitting in" then fall apart trying to reach an aesthetic zenith.

Comment: I'm not suggesting intuitive design. Quite the opposite. I'm suggesting learning some fundamentals. Such as, for instance, the differences between "Intuitive", "Efficient" and "Discoverable", and why the latter two are desirable, and the first one is way overrated.

Answer (score 1):

I have read Spolsky's book *User Interface Design for Programmers*, as well as the classics *The Windows Interface Guidelines for Software Design* and *Windows User Experience.*  The latter two are/were good reference books.  Spolsky's book is a wonderfully entertaining read and teaches you how to think about user interface design.

For my money, though, the best way to design the user interface of a desktop application is to duplicate existing solutions from popular software.  And by "duplicating," I'm referring to two distinct facets - the mechanism and the aesthetics.

As far as the **mechanism** is concerned, make sure your UI works the way people expect it to work.  For example, if you have a treeview, make sure the keyboard arrows work for navigation.  If your form has a scrollbar, make sure it responds to the scroll wheel on your mouse.  By and large, the .NET controls provide the standard behavior by default, but you may have to configure some of the design-time properties to fully achieve this.  I had a controls library I was working with a few years back that provided a standard textbox.  What I discovered, though, was that the text was not automatically highlighted when I tabbed into the control.  I added that behavior because it's the way I (and my users) expected the control to work.  Quoting Spolsky, "consistency causes ease of use, which, in turn, causes good feelings..."  In other words, if the mechanisms of your UI does not match what your users expect, your UI will be a source of frustration for your users.

As far as the **aesthetics** is concerned, I have discovered that focusing on things like fonts, icons, spacing between and alignment of controls, selective use of color (I love using gradients), etc. can go a LONG way toward adding that sense of polish to your user interface.  I've been known to use bitmap screen captures in Paint to measure the padding between controls in order to mimic the padding in the Microsoft applications.  When I divulge that information to co-workers, most of them look at me as though I've lost my mind.  But I cannot tell you the number of user interface successes I've had simply by focusing on what everyone else considers insignificant.  I chalk that up to simply leveraging all of the research Microsoft has ever done in making their applications visually appealing.

So my recommendation would be to read Spolsky's book and then try to duplicate as much of the Microsoft apps as you can.  For desktop applications, it's the surest approach.

Answer (score 1):

Take some time and look at *other* software products.  Every year, companies like Google and Microsoft dump millions of dollars into usability testing.  Take what they have learned about user interaction and apply it to your own products/projects.

Infragistics also just created a nice reference for UI Design Patterns, it can be found at http://quince.infragistics.com/.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to Windows UI guidelines or Mac UI guidelines.

Mac UI guidelines are available at http://developer.apple.com/documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGIntro/chapter_1_section_1.html

Windows UI guidelines are available at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx

EDIT:
Everybody likes the Google UI here is the [link](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/03/googles-design-guidelines.html).

Comment: Read both, but make sure not to confuse the two.  While Windows and OSX are similar in appearance, Windows is more "application-centric" while OSX is more "document-centric".  Basically, make sure you apply mac principles to the mac, and windows principles to windows.

Comment: the vendor specific guidelines aren't really a good place to start learning about gui design. They only really help with keeping consistent with other applications on the platform. Analogy to code: It's like learning Java, without learning any of the CS fundamentals.

Comment: Since we will develop our applications run on the specific operating systems, I feel we should follow the specific OS UI guidelines

Comment: Yes that's fine, right? But to continue the analogy, just coding in the Java style doesn't garauntee that you will write good code, if you don't understand data structures, algorithms, etc. etc. It's the same with UI design. There are fundamentals these guides don't cover, but are more important.

Comment: To state it bluntly, reading these guides will not result in good interface design. It will only prevent stupendously bad interface design. Mediocre is the best you can hope for.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best idea is to practice. I like designing my windows on paper first (blank or graph paper). Use a ruler and make sure things align and are clean.

> An example comes to mind from my project at work where I had to use 127 buttons to represent 127 computers in our lab. :/

Ask questions to yourself here, what didn't I like about it? How can it be improved? Did I need drop down or a list box for the computers?

Also know your [GUI widgets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUI_widget).

Comment: Practice is useless without a useful method of evaluation. User testing in this case is far superior to self critique. It is generally the case that the software developer, no matter how savvy, or how good a design sense, has no idea what will happen when someone else uses their stuff

Comment: The developer is the first user you have to please :) apparently the poster wasn't doing that ;)

Answer (score 0):

The answers already give some great books on how to specifically design interfaces. I'd like to help with some suggestions to help you improve your *nose* for design. Some of these might be cheaply available 2nd-hand, or something you can borrow locally (I'm always willing to lend books to people in Perth, Western Australia):

- Bill Buxton's [Sketching user Experiences](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123740371) - buy it, read the stories and start practicing sketching
- Nathaniel Borenstein's (out of print) [Programming as if People Mattered](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691037639) -  a superb little book of anecdotes
- Jeff Johnson's [GUI Bloopers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123706432) which will help you with lots of pragmatic examples of design gone wrong, in both desktop and web application design.